# Control Masks Programmatically for Simulink block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a problem with simulink block properties. I need to check if block has parameter with name "paramName". If this parameter is absent I need to add it.
For this I want to get mask parameters:

```
p = Simulink.Mask.get(blockName);
```

This example I get from help. But Simulink show following error:

> undefined variable "Simulink" or class "Simulink.Mask.get"

What should I do for solving my problem?

Comment: Actually, reading up on the doc (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/control-masks-programmatically.html), this should work. Which release of MATLAB are you using? It may this functionality isn't available in your release. The work described below with `get_param` should work though (the doc suggests using other properties such as `MaskVariables`, etc...)

Comment: I am using MATLAB R2011b (7.13.0.564) 64-bits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can check if parameter exists. For this I am use your code and "isfield" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use [`get_param`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/get_param.html) in combination with the `DialogParameters` property, e.g.:

```
block_params = get_param(%block_path%,`DialogParameters`);
```

The output `block_params` is a structure with all the parameters of that particular block. Replace `%block_path%` by the path to the block in question or use `gcb` for the current block. There is an example on the documentation page for `get_param`:

> **Get a Block Parameter Value and Attributes**
>
> List the block parameter
>   names for the `Inertia` block in the `Requisite Friction` subsystem of the
>   `sldemo_clutch` model.

```
block_params = get_param('sldemo_clutch/Friction Mode Logic/Requisite Friction/Inertia Ratio',... 'DialogParameters') 

ans = 
                                          Gain: [1x1 struct]
                             Multiplication: [1x1 struct]
                                 ParamMin: [1x1 struct]
                                ParamMax: [1x1 struct]
                  ParamDataTypeStr: [1x1 struct]
                                     OutMin: [1x1 struct]
                                    OutMax: [1x1 struct]
                      OutDataTypeStr: [1x1 struct]
                                LockScale: [1x1 struct]
                                  RndMeth: [1x1 struct]
    SaturateOnIntegerOverflow: [1x1 struct]
                             SampleTime: [1x1 struct]
```